# Hide Header for Login Component

Tags: angular

I have one header component and body component in app.component.

```
    <app-header></app-header>
    <div class="body">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

I want to hide  header element if I am in login component. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlets-ke7cyk?file=app/login/login.component.html) Here you can use `(activate)` event to detect changes of component.

```
  <app-header *ngIf="isShow"></app-header>
    <div class="body">
       <router-outlet (activate)="showHideNav($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

then in appcomponent.ts create one bool param

```
isShow=false;
```

and write function

```
 showHideNav(event){
    this.isShow= !(event instanceof LoginComponent);                                        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define that on app route level, for example if its '/login'

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' }
```

login.component.html

```
<h1>Login Page</h1>
```

if its '/someroute'

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'someroute', loadChildren: './someroute/someroute.module#SomeRouteModule'}
```

someroute.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="body">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a property in component and check in every single route isn't appears to be the best way to handle this problem. What if in future you needs to hide those things for many routes?

Here i have find a sample project Github repo that shows the way to handle this problem

repo - https://github.com/IanValente/IanValente.github.io/tree/master

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of link external's code, it is better to provide some minimal example, giving credit in a link, in a better format, like [example repo](https://github.com/IanValente/IanValente.github.io/tree/master). This way, if the code is removed by external source, the minimal example and due credit will be here forever.